# Proper way to read to the end of file when having multiples data types c++

Tags: c++, eof

I made a simple program that calculates price for items sold. And saves the information into a a file. I am trying to read from this file which contains a string and integers. What is a good way to read to the end of file? I am currently using EOF function but is not working correctly. It repeats the last two lines.

```
 void viewTransactions();
 void viewTransactions()
{
    string productName,;
    int quantity, totalPrice;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("transactions.txt");
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
    getline(infile, productName);
    infile >> quantity;
    infile >> totalPrice;
    infile.ignore(100, '\n');

    cout << productName << endl;
    cout << quantity << endl;
    cout << totalPrice << endl;


    }
}
```

"transactions.txt" contains:

```
Product
1
5
Product
2
10
Product
3
15
```

Console Output File When Read:

```
Product
1
5
Product
2
10
Product
3
15

3
15
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample text file? I mean 2-3 lines of the "transactions.txt".

Comment: @gsamaras I inserted what you asked for, can you take a look plz.

Comment: Thanks Hugo. You made a classic mistake, thus I prompted your question to the canonical link. Moreover, @BasileStarynkevitch already suggested a workaround (I didn't check it), thus my work here is done. Good luck! =)

Answer (score 0):

`infile.`[`eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) is valid only *after* a read operation (not "before"). And [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can set the [`eofbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate), so better code:

```
for(;;) {
  getline(infile, productName);
  if (infile.eof()) break;
  infile >> quantity;
  infile >> totalPrice;
```

etc... (or use a `do` ... `while(!infile.eof())` loop).

There is a reason for that (at least on POSIX e.g. Linux): there is no way, at the OS level (i.e. using system calls listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) to magically test that EOF condition, it is a result of some *previous* [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) operation.

BTW, you probably should compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then **use the debugger `gdb`** and you'll have found that bug yourself.